Is rubbing in the ass of girl is comit as zinah
When I was 16 years old I slept with my cousin late night when she was sleeping
I undresss her and put my penis from back and ejaculate in her so I want to know that is I did zina??

Undoubtedly and unquestionably it was a zina there is no room to shoow a kind of "leniency" upon you like "you didn't know" or you was "too young" or "immatured" so the answer is a "BIG YES" that akhi you have indeed committed zina and please don't expose your sin to everyone now anymore because Prophet AS said that whole of my ummah will be forgiven except a "muhajir" so it was asked who is that person like what's the kind so he SAW said that a person who expose his sins to people very normally even if Allah has put pardah upon it so please repent as what you have did was not natural or playful or immaturity or by mistake and rest Allah said "even if you say it aloud or in silent but Allah knows what is in every heart" in Surah Mulk so please repent Allah is often forgiving and merciful he loves those who turns towards him with hope and accept your mistake that it was a sin that is what Allah loves the most the honesty and regression and as Allah said "do not even go nearby to adultery verily it is a disastrous thing" in Surah Al-isra and every son of Adam commits sin but the best among those is the one who repent and in another narration Prophet SAW said that "the one who truly repents from a sin is like the one who never did it" so repent is an opportunity for every mu'min so please don't loose it Allah is often forgiving and merciful May Allah forgive and guide you ameen.
